# highcharts 'stackY' is not using the 'valueDecimals' attribut

Tags: highcharts

i am using this code to display the tooltip of a multiple series chart:

```
tooltip:{useHTML:true,
valueDecimals:0,
valueSuffix:" ms",
pointFormat:"<div class=\\\"cartouche\\\"><div  style=\\\"background-color:{series.color};    height:10px;width:10px;float:left;\\\"><\/div><span>{series.name}:     <b>{point.y} - {point.stackY} ms<\/b><\/span><\/div>"
}
```

The **point.stackY** doesn't use the *valueDecimals* value.

Is this a bug ?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it looks like a bug, so I've reported it to our developers (https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1872), but you can use formatter:

http://jsfiddle.net/UGzaT/2/

```
 formatter:function(){
            return '<div class="cartouche"><div  style="background-color:'+this.series.color+';    height:10px;width:10px;float:left;"><\/div><span>'+this.series.name+':     <b>'+Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y,0)+' - '+Highcharts.numberFormat(this.total,0)+' ms<\/b><\/span><\/div>'
        }
```

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.numberFormat()